# What is the difference between 'main' and 'renderer' folders 'electron-webpack'?

Tags: webpack, electron

I don't understand the specific use for /renderer folder, and how does it differ from the /main one.

Official electron-webpack docs suggest the use of a 'renderer' folder for compiling the project (With default config for `electron-webpack dev`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron has two processes

The main process: This is a JS file that runs when you open the app. This is where you create your window, and point it to (usually) an HTML file. 
This HTML file runs exactly like it would in chrome. Except you can include nodejs libraries. 
The HTML file you open is ran under the **Render Process**

So you basically always have two JavaScript files running. The *Main* which interfaces with the OS and the *Render* which is where most the code goes, and works much more like a browser

For example if you did 
Console.Log in the main process. It would not show up in the chrome web console. 
However if you did it in the Render process it would